# Flot Series label undefined

Tags: jquery, graph, jquery-plugins, flot

Im struggling to get my pie chart to show the correct label, rather than "undefined".

In my console log, the labels are there, and the amounts are being shown.

```
[ { label: "Opened", data: 5}, { label: "Qualified", data: 6}, { label: "Closed", data: 1}, { label: "Pending", data: 2},];
```

This is made from an $.each function that receives the data from an ajax query.

I have the below script creating the graph:

```
var dataOut = "[";
$.each(value, function(item2, val2){
    dataOut = dataOut + ' { label: "' + val2[0] + '", data: ' + val2[1] + '},';
});
dataOut = dataOut + "];";

var placeholder = $("#graph_myleads");

$.plot(placeholder, dataOut, {
    series: {
        pie: { 
            show: true,
            radius: 3/4,
            label: {
                show: true,
                radius: 3/4,
                formatter: _labelFormatter,
                background: {
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    color: '#000'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    }
});
```

and the below formatter for the label:

```
var _labelFormatter = function(label, series) {
    return "<div style='font-size:8pt; text-align:center; padding:2px; color:white;'>" + series.label + "<br/>" + Math.round(series.percent) + "%</div>";
};
```

The code is currently outputting this:

[image]

Any help on this one would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Output `label` instead of `series.label`.

```
var _labelFormatter = function(label, series) {
    console.log(dataOut);
    return "<div style='font-size:8pt; text-align:center; padding:2px;     color:white;'>" + label + "<br/>" + Math.round(series.percent) + "%</div>";
};
```

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x3z1zpzv/

Only thing I chaned is indeed `label` instead of `series.label`, and I called the labelformatter as a named function instead of a function expression, as it seemed to ignore the css color 'white' otherwise.

Comment: Done the same, still getting the same problem. I'm thinking it is something to do with receiving the data from an ajax request and it seeing it as a string as Raidri above noticed. Problem is, I need this to be dynamic, not static

Answer (score 0):

You have your data as array (which is what flot needs) but then you build a string from that and try to give that to flot. Just change the `$.each` loop to build an array.

```
var dataOut = [];
$.each(data, function (item2, val2) {
    dataOut.push( { label: val2[0], data: val2[1] });
});

$.plot(placeholder, dataOut, { ... });
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuo3qer3/1/) for the working code.

Comment: can't do this, I am getting the data from an ajax query, so cannot hard code the data into the script, which you likely would have seen from the $.each function that is there.

Comment: Then change the `$.each` loop to build an array instead of a string. See updated answer.